# How to configure Untangle OpenVPN client to connect to a n ordinary (non-Untangle) OpenVPN server?

Tags: openvpn, untangle

Choosing Untangle I was hoping that I could set its OpenVPN client-mode facility to connect to my OpenVPN server (which I've manually set up on a dedicated server, not in another office, the purpose is to secure client-server connections, not to interconnect branches). But it seems that it is not manually configurable and is only meant to connect to another Untangle box set up as an OpenVPN server (by means of an Untangle-OpenVPN-server-generated zip config package).

Is there a way to bypass this and connect an Untangle box to a normal OpenVPN server?

If you run Untangle with OpenVPN server enabled, maybe you could share (wiping your sensitive data before ofcourse) a config.zip for me to hack?

Answer (score 1):

why not generate the keys corresponding to your OpenVPN server? if you have OpenVPN running then i presume you must have your own CA configured. you can just sign new certificates and zip them and distribute to clients.

Comment: That is exactly what I meant to do, but I didn't knew the internal structure of Untangle OpenVPN configuration zipfiles. Now I've already figured it out. I think I'll post it here as the answer later so that others can make use of this Q/A.